# Matching data in two columns

Tags: excel, match

I have an excel sheet with a series of last and first names in columns B and C.  I'm trying to match names to those in a second sheet in columns A and B.  Not every name will match and first or last names might be duplicate but assume never both.  I've tried this

`=IF((MATCH(B3,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$150,0)*MATCH(C3,Sheet1!B1,0))>1,1,0)`

It kind of work but there is nothing stopping excel from matching the last name and then going to a separate line entry to find the first name.

Can somebody please show me how to make excel only search the same row for the last name as it found the first?

Comment: Could you please show sample data and output?  Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm clear about the thing you try to do, but I've two suggestions:

1. Is this the way you want it to work?

   =IF((MATCH(B3,Sheet1!A:A,0))*AND(MATCH(C3,Sheet1!B:B,0))>1,1,0)
2. What if you make third column in each sheet, using:

   =CONCATENATE("CELL WITH A FIRST NAME", " ", "CELL WITH A LAST NAME")

stretched down to the whole data. Then you can do your match between this 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

With first names in column A, last names in column B on sheet 1, and first name in B3, last name in C3 on current sheet:

```
=match(B3&C3,index(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$150&Sheet1!$B$1:$B$150,0),0)
```

Formula in D3 returns the position of the found match:

[image]

Don't use with whole column references. It will be slow to recalculate.